# How do Runesmith and Eschew Materials interact?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, class-feature, prestige-class

How do the Runesmith prestige class’ runes interact with the Eschew Materials feat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A runesmith cannot get around the runic material component by means of an ability or feat such as Eschew Materials, although he can use such feats and abilities to waive any other material components for a spell he prepares in rune form, subject to the limitations of the ability.